# How to Export Stored Procedure Output to Text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need your support to come up with the solution.

I have 10 different set of stored procedures which I have to export into text file, all 10 procedures will return the same set of columns (only calling parameters are different).

I am not getting the solution how to do ?

Could you please help me to understand how to export the data from a stored procedure output to tab delimited text file?

Also if possible can tell me in SSIS package too.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this labelled both SQL Server and MySQL?  Which database are you using?

Comment: It should probably be MSSQL... you know how things work here

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution here.

For each SP:

- execute SP in Management Studio
- underneath in Results Pane, right-click and choose Save Results As...
- under Save As Type select CSV

At the end, open each file in notepad and simply concatenate results.

**EDIT**

If you have e.g. 10 stored procedures, you could do the following:

- create temporary table for output

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #output (...)
  ```
- use 10 `INSERT...EXEC`'s to fill temp table

  ```
  INSERT INTO #output EXEC MySP1 ...
  GO
  INSERT INTO #output EXEC MySP2 ...
  GO
  INSERT INTO #output EXEC MySP3 ...
  GO
  ...
  INSERT INTO #output EXEC MySP10 ...
  GO
  ```
- execute query `SELECT * FROM #output`
- underneath in Results Pane, right-click and choose Save Results As...
- under Save As Type select CSV

**EDIT 2**

If you wish to have an information in your output temp table where you data came from (which SP), you may add another column to your SP, in order to have a bit of control over INSERT...EXEC statement.

If you wish to do that but can't control the SP output, one way to do it is to control the default value of `#output` and another is to dd another temp table for intermediate results. I would use the second one:

- create temporary table for output, with e.g. your table name as identifier.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #output (spname sysname, ...)
  ```
- create temporary table for intermediate result

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #temp (...)
  ```
- use 10 `INSERT...EXEC`'s to fill intermediate and then output table

  ```
  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
  INSERT INTO #temp EXEC MySP1 ...
  GO
  INSERT INTO #output
  SELECT spname = 'MySP1', * FROM #temp
  GO

  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
  INSERT INTO #temp EXEC MySP2 ...
  GO
  INSERT INTO #output
  SELECT spname = 'MySP2', * FROM #temp
  GO
  ...
  ```
- execute query `SELECT * FROM #output`
- underneath in Results Pane, right-click and choose Save Results As...
- under Save As Type select CSV

Comment: Hi Ozren, Thanks for your comment. however i need different approach, since i have to run manually all the 10 SP.

Comment: Is there any other way that we can get the output from SP ?

Comment: Thanks Ozren , Let me check

Comment: Ozren its working fine , if possible can we add one identity column in each SP ?Studentid Firstname Lastname Email    Identity 
1   Vivek  Johari  vivek@abc.com        SP1 
2   Pankaj  Kumar  pankaj@abc.com   SP2 
3   Amit  Singh  amit@abc.com         SP3
4   Manish  Kumar  manish@abc.comm      SP4
5   Abhishek Singh  abhishek@abc.com     SP5

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand, but if you want to identify to which one of your SP's the rows belong, easiest way would be to add one column to your SP1 ... SP10 output.

Comment: yes just wanted to know about data which query belong to which SP, but i don't have permission to alter the SP in production server, DO you have any idea pls suggest me

Comment: Sorry Ozren , here i am getting error msg : An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
Dont know what was the problem ?

Comment: This is a different problem. It's very likely that your SP is using another INSERT EXEC construct. Unfortunately you can't do much about that apart from finding some workaround. You don't have a simple situation here, and I am starting to believe that a SSIS package would be a better solution for this...

Comment: Hi Ozren , Is there any way to do in SSIS package level ?

Comment: If I were to do this in SSIS, I would enumerate all sources, loop over them and export to csv files and merge them at the end. Here's tutorial on how to [loop over files](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx), I guess you can apply it to loop over stored procedures as well.